# No absolutely consistent foundation for math: logically possible?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics

Is it logically possible that there really is *no* absolutely consistent formal system, already discovered or yet undiscovered, that can serve as a foundation for mathematics?

Comment: @EliranH I believe ZF is a formal system.

Comment: Title and body of your posting: they are really two different question. Would you mind updating the answer to clarify what you're interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Yes, it is logically possible that there is no consistent formal system that can serve as a foundation for mathematics.

This follows immediately from Gödel's second Incompleteness theorem, which proves that that no consistent axiomatic system which includes Peano arithmetic (or stronger) can prove its own consistency.

Assuming that any such foundational theory T is such an effectively generated formal system, i.e an axiomatic theory expressive enough to develop basic properties of the natural numbers, T cannot prove its own consistency. Thus is it *logically possible* that it is inconsistent.

## 2. No, it is highly unlikely that there are no consistent foundations for mathematics.

This would mean that every conceivable candidate is inconsistent. But this is not what our mathematical practice tells us.

The assumption that de facto candidates for such a foundational theory of mathematics (ZFC plus some other axioms) are consistent is not a simple convention. Logicians apply ampliative reasoning usually found in the science and think they have some good measure of inductive support to believe that they these candidates are consistent: they have been working with ZFC for almost a century and have never encountered an inconsistency. (Cf. this with the discovery of the inconsistency of Frege's system, which was discovered by Russell while Frege's publication was still in press.)

---

Note that we might be able to prove the consistency of such a foundational theory *relative* to the assumed consistency of another theory: If ZFC is consistent, so is ZFC plus some axiom. But this is not what you're after, I guess?

Comment: Your first point hits the nail in the head, I'm quite ashamed to not have noticed it myself. Also, thanks for the insightful second point, which is not really about my question, but is an interesting read anyway.

Comment: The second point is not supported.  We took forever to find the inconsistencies in earlier systems.  They are just not near the surface.  And we have proposed all kinds of workarounds that can be verified to solve the problems *that we see*.  But it is not our mathematical experience that systems we trust do not ultimately have paradoxes farther down.  It is our experience from Pythagoras forward that they are inconsistent, but can be patched endlessly.

Comment: Your first point relies on a mathematical theorem. Can you really conclude that it's logically possible that the whole of math is inconsistent *based on a mathematical theorem*?

Comment: ZF has been proven (from the "outside") to be Post consistent, by Godel himself no less. The Continuum Hypothesis can be neither proved nor disproved in ZF.

Comment: Re: point 2, I took it as a given that a foundation for mathematics must be a foundation for *all* mathematics. Even if ZFC is "foundational" (and it is), we know for sure that it's not a consistent foundation for all mathematics because it is incomplete. Godel's theorems tell us that we will never have such a foundation, only incomplete "foundational" systems.

Comment: @EliranH: Sure, we can! That's the consequence of the so-called [principle of explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) and ZFC is formulated in a classical logic. If ZFC is inconsistent, then we can mathematically prove any statement A and its negation, including Gödel's theorems. Inconsistency doesn't mean that we can't prove anything. It means that we can prove everything!

Comment: @Era: 1. "we know for sure that it's not a consistent foundation for all mathematics because it is incomplete": I don't follow your reasoning. From incompleteness it doesn't follow that ZFC is inconsistent, just that we can't prove that it consistent.

Comment: @Era: 2. "Godel's theorems tell us that we will never have such a foundation, only incomplete "foundational" systems": I don't follow. The question here is about consistency, not completeness. An inconsistent system wouldn't give much of a foundation, sure, but an incomplete system (ZFC plus some further axioms) can give foundation for *all* actual mathematics. (In case you wonder: the "multiverse view" in phil of set theory is a different kind of beast.)

Comment: @jobermark: I agree that there's a possibility of "deep inconsistency", not "near the surface" as you say. It's a very interesting issue. But I don't follow your remark that previous axiomatic systems were widely inconsistent. Can you point me to some examples? I know of math that was thought to be inconsistent, but indeed was not: e.g. [Saccheri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Girolamo_Saccheri)'s proof by contradiction actually produced theorems of hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: @DBK 1. To clarify, it's not a consistent foundation **for all mathematics** because it's incomplete. I was negating the whole thing, not just the consistency part. ZFC is known to be consistent and incomplete. 2. How can an **incomplete** system give a foundation for **all** mathematics? Since CH is undecidable in ZFC, you can consistently extend ZFC with either CH or its negation. Both extensions have interesting properties that mathematicians want to study, but they can't both be encompassed under a single foundational system (at least, not using extensions of ZF).

Comment: @Era: The question hinges on what "all mathematics" means. Does "all mathematics" includes the system (and the math domain) that serves as its foundation or not? The more orthodox view is that it does not. This is the view I am using. So as long we can deduce from it all statements that have arisen as theorems in traditional math (geometry, analysis, etc.) except set theory, we have a foundation for all mathematics, haven't we? If one takes the view that "all mathematics" means all statements expressible in a mathematical language, including set-theoretic ones, then you're completely right.

Comment: @DBK No, the problem is not limited to meta-statements. Godel's proof of the incompleteness theorems demonstrates that the two cannot be separated. The Godel sentence is a statement **in** number theory, in addition to being a statement about provability in a particular formalization of number theory. You can't extend the axioms to get rid of Godel sentences.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my point. I don't want to get rid of Gödel sentences or undecidable statements. My point is: You won't find the Gödel sentence in a book about number theory. As long as all interesting theorems in number theory can be proved in the foundational system, it's a foundation enough, given the limits shown by Gödel.

Comment: I did not suggest things have been 'widely inconsistent', but that we keep discovering aspects that contradict our current standards: irrational numbers, sets of measure zero, multiple infinities, etc. and finally the problems with negation.  For Pythagoreans, for instance, a number *was* a ratio, so the discovery of irrationality was a contradiction.  The problems with undefined derivatives and with infinitesimals were real problems, not just the minor expansions that history has rewritten them into...

Comment: @jobermark: My second point is about formal, not "conceptual" inconsistency. I dig your point that the history of math is not removed from conjectures and refutations, as Lakatos would have put it. I think we agree, then.

Comment: I think we do.  But still one quibble, there is not really a distinction between formal and conceptual inconsistency, we press our standards back on the past, but in their own terms, formal reality was the way they conceived it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me first point out that a *consistency proof* is something carried out *within mathematics*.

Now, assume PA is your foundation-candidate. Is it consistent? Well, [Gödel's second incompleteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem) shows that PA cannot prove its own consistency. So you must assume some *stronger theory*, say ZF, in order to prove PA consistent (it is well known that PA's consistency can be proven within ZF).

But, you may now ask, *is ZF consistent*? Of course, ZF cannot prove its own consistency (Gödel), so again you must assume some stronger theory to prove ZF consistent.

This can go on. In the end, you must assume *something*. You must take some mathematical theory to be the background theory with which you work in mathematics, and you have to take its consistency on faith (or rather on the fact that no one has ever found a contradiction within it).

Comment: Sorry to have misled you, I was talking about absolute consistency.

Comment: @Constantine but what exactly do you mean by that? My point is that some math has to be used in the background. See my comment to the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

The current formalist approach, officially retreating from the inconsistencies in ordinary logic back to what is formalizable, kind of proves that if there is no natural formalization of mathematics, we will simply declare one.  From the point of view of the other contenders in the argument over the natural foundations of mathematics, this is the current state of affairs.  Formalists won by fiat, we *simply will have formalization* because **that is the way it is supposed to be**.  Then we all went back to being closet Platonists and ignoring the natural holes in human logic.

From a neo-Intuitionist point of view, this is to be expected.  If mathematics is the repository of abstract intuitions that are adequately widely shared, instead of being a study of some real logical core at the center of reality, then in order to share it widely, we need to feel good about its internal consistency.  Mathematics is meant to codify and collect our logic, so if it extends outside the bounds of our trust in our own logic, we will just circumscribe it for our own comfort.

There may be wars over the best formalism, but in the end we accept that there should be one, and if worse comes to worst, we will simply choose.